# How to create a subscribe that listens for when you unclick the mouse button for drag and drop functionality in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In onNodeClick() method I need to create a subscribe that listens for when you unclick the mouse button for drag and drop functionality using angular.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what implementation of drag&drop you're using, but in general I think that listening to a `mouseup` event could do the trick.

You can probably also consider using the `Drag and Drop` module from Angular CDK, which gives you all the functionality and events that you need: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 0):

For your service that listens to mouse actions you could try an implementation like so

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'

private Subject = new Subject<any>()

@HostListener('mouseup')
onMouseup() {
    // if you unpress the mouse button this emmit true 
    this.Subject.next('true')
  }
}

@HostListener('mousedown')
onMousedwon() {
    // if you press the mouse button 
    this.Subject.next()
  }
}

getClick(){
  return this.Subject.asObservable()
}
```

In the *.component.ts you can listen for your mouse clicks and do certain stuff when the click is happening in the if part of the function

```
import { DragDropService } from 'src/...'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'

private sub: Subscritption

constructor( private service: DragDropService) {
 this.sub = this.service.getClick().subscribe(mouse => {
 if(mouse) {
  // do your stuff here

  // if your done just do
  this.sub.unsubscribe()
 } else { 
  // do something while not holding
 }
```